# for it not to be fun

Tags: comprehension

> None of the multimedia that enhances business, personal, and family use of a PC could exist without sound capabilities. Multimedia CD-ROMs and DVDs bring their subjects to life in ways not possible in books, because you hear the actual sounds of whales, wars, and warblers, of sopranos, space blaster shots, and saxophones. Not that sound capabilities must always enlighten you on a topic. You should have fun with your PC, too. It won't make the work day shorter to replace Windows's error chime with Homer Simpson saying, "D'oh!" You won't be more productive every time a Windows program opens or closes if it
>   makes a sound like those doors in Star Trek. And you'll spend more time than you should creating an MP3 song collection from your stockpiles of music CDs. But so what? Taking advantage of the sounds in a multimedia PC personalizes a machine that has a rap for being impersonal. Sound simply adds to the fun of
>   using your computer. And we all spend too much time in front of these things **for it not to be fun.**

I don't think I comprehend that last line well. What's that really say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says basically

> If we consider that ***it*** (our spending "too much time in front of these things") ***is not fun***, then we ***cannot justify*** devoting so much time to it.

In other words, one can only deduce that it **must be fun** since we spend so much time doing it.

Answer (score 0):

It's saying "since we spend so much time using computers, it would be disappointing to not have fun using a computer".